# Remove carriage return from stringvar holding bookmarked text

Tags: vba, ms-word

In a Word 2010 VBA macro, I copied bookmarked text to a string variable named "strMsgBoxMsg".

I want to remove carriage returns from the text associated with a bookmark named "Title", but I can't remove the carriage returns in the bookmarked text.

The following does NOT remove the carriage returns:

```
string2FindAndDelete1 = " " & Chr(13) & " "
string2FindAndDelete1 = " " & vbCrLf
string2FindAndDelete1 = " " & Chr(13)
string2FindAndDelete1 = Chr(13) & " "

If InStr(FnA.fnEnumerateDocBkMrks, "Title") Then
    strMsgBoxMsg = ""
    strMsgBoxMsg = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Title").Range.Text
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, string2FindAndDelete1, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%")
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, string2FindAndDelete2, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%")
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, string2FindAndDelete3, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%")
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%", " ")
    MsgBox "MessageBox after Search and Replace:" & vbCrLf & strMsgBoxMsg
End If
```

I posted the Word file to the web at this address:  http://tinyurl.com/h7vul2p

The VBA macro in the file is:  subSaveAsPdfInSameDir

Comment: You assign four different values to the same variable?

Comment: Is there always a space preceding or following the paragraph marks? If there's only a paragraph mark then none of the assignments you make will work. Try just vbCr (without the LF) OR Chr(13). And, as Tim implies in his question, note that only the last of the variable assignments to the same variable name is going to work - VBA won't remember all of them, only the last one...

Comment: I can't believe how sloppy I was, even though I spent a few hours looking at an obvious error I made.

Answer (score 0):

Below are my corrections, which worked, thanks to Cindy and Tim (who deserve the credit, but I can't figure out how to give them the credit for solving my problem).

My goal was to end up with one space between the last word on one line, and the first word on the next line of the modified text.

I had intended the top four variables to have different names (e.g., string2FindAndDelete1, string2FindAndDelete2, etc.

```
string2FindAndDelete1 = " " & Chr(13) & " "
string2FindAndDelete2 = " " & Chr(13)
string2FindAndDelete3 = Chr(13) & " "
string2FindAndDelete4 = Chr(13)


If InStr(fn_EnumerateDocBkMrks, "Title") Then
    strMsgBoxMsg = ""
    strMsgBoxMsg = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Title").Range.Text
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, string2FindAndDelete1, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%")
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, string2FindAndDelete2, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%")
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, string2FindAndDelete3, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%")
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, string2FindAndDelete4, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%")
    strMsgBoxMsg = Replace(strMsgBoxMsg, "%%REPLACE_THIS%%", " ")
    MsgBox "MessageBox after Search and Replace Carriage Returns:" & vbCr & vbCrLf & strMsgBoxMsg
    Call subWriteProp(sPropName:="Title", sValue:=strMsgBoxMsg)
End If
```